# Why isn't broadcasting with numpy faster than a nested loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested-loops, array-broadcasting

I have a calculation in my code that get carried out thousands of times and I wanted to see if I could make it faster as it is currently using two nested loops. I assumed that if I used broadcasting I could make it several times faster.

I've shown the two options below, which thankfully give the same results.

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000
x = np.random.random([n, 3])
y = np.random.random([n, 3])
func_weight = np.random.random(n)


result = np.zeros([n, 9])
result_2 = np.zeros([n, 9])

# existing
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(3):
        result[:, 3*a + b] = x[:, a] * y[:, b] * func_weight

# broadcasting - assumed this would be faster
for a in range(3):
    result_2[:, 3*a:3*(a+1)] = np.expand_dims(x[:, a], axis=-1) * y * np.expand_dims(func_weight, axis=-1)
```

### Timings

```
n=100
nested loops: 24.7 µs ± 362 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
broadcasting: 70.3 µs ± 1.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

n=1000
nested loops: 50.5 µs ± 913 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
broadcasting: 148 µs ± 372 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

n=10000
nested loops: 327 µs ± 7.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
broadcasting: 864 µs ± 5.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

In my testing, broadcasting is always slower, so I'm a little confused as to what is happening. I'm guessing that because I had to use `expand_dims` to get the shapes aligned in the second solution, that is what the big impact on performance is. Is that correct? As the array size grows, there's not much change in performance with the nested loop always about 3 times quicker.

Is there a more optimal third solution that I haven't considered?

Comment: Replacing a few loops on a complex operation won't give you much, if any improvement.  We see the biggest improvements with many loops on simple operations.  That said, I'll have to take time to repeat your tests and see if I can be better speeds. I suspect producing a (n,3,3) solution will be faster and easier (it can be reshaped after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [126]: %%timeit
     ...: result = np.zeros([n,9])
     ...: for a in range(3):
     ...:     for b in range(3):
     ...:         result[:, 3*a + b] = x[:, a] * y[:, b] * func_weight
141 µs ± 255 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [128]: %%timeit
     ...: result_2 = np.zeros([n,9])
     ...: for a in range(3):
     ...:    result_2[:, 3*a:3*(a+1)] = np.expand_dims(x[:, a], axis=-1) * y * n
     ...: p.expand_dims(func_weight, axis=-1)
202 µs ± 10.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

A fully broadcasted version:

```
In [130]: %%timeit
     ...: result_3 = (x[:,:,None]*y[:,None,:]*func_weight[:,None,None]).reshape(
     ...: n,9) 
88.8 µs ± 73.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Replacing the `expand_dims` with `np.newaxis/None` expansion:

```
In [131]: %%timeit
     ...: result_2 = np.zeros([n,9])
     ...: for a in range(3):
     ...:    result_2[:, 3*a:3*(a+1)] = x[:, a,None] * y * func_weight[:,None]
132 µs ± 315 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So yes, `expand_dims` is a bit slow, I think because it tries to be general purpose. And an extra layer of function calls.

`expand_dims` is just `a.reshape(shape)`, but it takes a bit of time to translate your axis parameter into the `shape` tuple.  As an experienced user I find that the `None` syntax is clearer (and faster) - visually it stands out as a dimension-adding action.

Comment: Interestingly your broadcast solutions are faster than mine, but still about twice as slow as the nested loop solution on my computer for n = 10000. At n=1000, the nested loop is only marginally master. I guess there must be some system dependence muddying the waters.

Comment: For large enough arrays, memory management becomes more complex and time consuming.  It's been often observed that a modest number of iterations on smaller arrays is faster.

Comment: what size was n in your example?